# Is there an ESlint rule for adding async when using await in a function?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, async-await, eslint

I sometimes start writing a function in JavaScript not knowing if I need it async or not. Then I need to use the await keyword : I would like ESlint to auto correct and add the `async` keyword to my function when doing so.

For instance :

```
function foo() {
  const bar = await baz()
}
```

would be transformed to :

```
async function foo() {
  const bar = await baz()
}
```

Is there an ESlint rule with auto-fix for that ?

Maybe someone will argue it does not make sense to auto-correct incorrect code into correct code. In that case, would that person have another suggestion for improving the ease of writing that type of code ?

EDIT : the code is not syntactly correct. Therefore ESlint will simply raise a "Parsing error". Therefore it's more a question for the text editor : would there be VS Code extension that adds a quick-fix option for that kind of syntax error ? "Mark the surrounding function as async", something of the kind ?

EDIT 2 : that would be particularly useful when creating tests.

```
it("is correct", () => {
  expect(isCorrect()).toBe(true)
})
```

and

```
it("is correct", async () => {
  expect(await isCorrect()).toBe(true)
})
```

are both valid syntax. When changing the code of a test to add an `await` keyword, it would be very useful for the function to mark itself as async automatically, rather than the current behaviour.

Comment: This is nothing a linter would do, it's a straight syntax error.

Comment: "*I sometimes start writing a function in JavaScript not knowing if I need it async or not*" - it sounds like you should take a bit more time to design your architecture before starting to write code. You should always have an idea of what a function would do, and being asynchronous or not is an important part of the contract. Don't simply "add an `async` keyword" because you think it could be handy. If you started out writing a synchronous method, try keeping it synchronous until you realise that you can't. When that happens, re-design with asynchrony in mind and start over.

Comment: Ok I understand it is a syntax error. Maybe it's more a VS Code question then ? VS Code shows me the syntax error in my code : I would love if it offered a "quick-fix tip" to make my function asynchronous.
I perfectly understand it has implications in my code, and an async function is not equivalent to a synchronous function. But sometimes, at a high level, I simply need a function that gets me back some result, asynchronous or not. And I love how async / await syntax allows me to quickly move to asynchronous code without changing everything.

Comment: I guess this could be a feature request for the JavaScript/TypeScript language server

Answer (score 0):

It works now with my setup! If anyone else has the issue still, I can dig further how to enable the same feature.

[image: VS code quick fix to add async modifier to containing function]